# How to show combined regions/continents in TeeChart map series?

Tags: c#-4.0, teechart

I am using TeeChart(4.1.2015.8062) for Winforms to display world map in our applicaton. This map can be displayed for predefined regions/continents. Teechart refers to this as world map types. e.g. available map types are - 
Africa, Asia, Australia, CentralAmerica, Europe, Europe15, Europe27, MiddleEast, NorthAmerica, SouthAmerica, Spain, USA, USAHawaiiAlaska, World.

We want to show map combined for Asia and Australia. Teechart 
currently displays separate maps Asia and Australia, but it does not have any provision to combine and display these two continents.

Does there exist any way to combine and display regions like - asia and australia or asia and middle east?

Thank you,

Sharad

Comment: Have you tried loading the world map and removing the undesired shapes? http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=9607&p=39521#p39521

Comment: Hi Yeray,  This I haven't tried, but will try and let you know,  Thanks